# plot multiple figures of smaller facets instead of one large figure of large facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want to use ggplot to produce histograms for all of my columns (132 columns). 
i use the following code but it produces all of histograms in one figure (132 tiny histograms). is there a way to produce for example 11 figures that each contains 12 histogram?

```
d <- melt(data)
ggplot(d,aes(x = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour="black", fill="white")+
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")
```

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will create a separate plot for each level of `variable` in your melted data and save it in a list.

```
p.list=list()

for (var in unique(d$variable)) {
    p.list[[var]] = ggplot(d[d$variable==var,], aes(x = value)) +
      facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") +
      geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),colour="black", fill="white")+
      geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666")
}
```

Now you can plot any number of them at a time. For example:

```
library(gridExtra)

for (i in seq(1, length(p.list), 12)) {
  do.call(grid.arrange, c(p.list[i:(i+11)], ncol=3))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually after inserting one parenthesis after 12 and removing ncol=3 ( because of the error "Error in do.call(grid.arrange, p.list[i:(i + 11)], ncol = 3) : unused argument (ncol = 3)" ) i got the following error : " Error in gList(R2 = list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,  :   only 'grobs' allowed in "gList" "

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it out without sample data. I've updated the code to address the `unused argument` error. The `only 'grobs'` error could occur if, for some reason, ggplot failed to create a plot for one of the values of `variable`, meaning that the corresponding list element doesn't contain a plot object, causing `grid.arrange` to fail.

Comment: What could cause ggplot to fail to produce a plot? One possibility is that there's only one row of data for at least one level of `variable`. This would cause `geom_density` to fail, and `p.list` would not contain a plot object for that level of `variable`. You can fix this by filtering out values of `variable` with only one row of non-missing data (assuming that's the cause).

Comment: I want to mention that the code is OK and work fine , the error for "grobs" was due to invalid index of 132 for p.list which has 131 elements.(actually there is 131 tiny histograms not 132, the code is written for 132) , thanks again